# 3d model turns black after making smaller In Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I downloaded [this](https://poly.google.com/view/dcrlVo3eQ_S) 3d model from poly.google.com
and I extracted the folder them imported to unity and until then it was fine the colors were good and everything (this is how it looked before resizing):

[image]

And because the model came too big so i had too resize but when i make it smaller this happens:

[image: image after resizing]

So what do I do?

Comment: Try to resize the object in the import settings. Go to the .fbx or .obj file you uploaded and in the inspector you see the import size of the file. Try to make it smaller there.

Comment: What are the scale factors in the inspector? I suspect there might negative scale factors...

Comment: In the import settings i see Scale Factor: 1. Is that bad?

Comment: Thanks ill try that solution @el6976.

Comment: It could also be with the camera settings some problem with hiding materials if it is far. You may need to look in that direction as well. Materials could also be a problem. Try to create 2 standard materials and assign these to your object with the same texture of course. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have the Scale Factor set to some extraneous value. Use 0.1 which is the default.

[image: Scale Factor]

Comment: I think this might be the problem because i have scale factor set to 1? or is that normal? And no i dont have any scripts attached to it yet. What exactly do you mean by kind of material?

Comment: If you use the materials the model came with it may be some problem due to format type. If you create the materials inside unity you are safer. Don't worry UV mapps will ve the same.

Comment: Actually yes that was the problem you solved it for me thanks:)